# What does the word on this Bierstein mean?

Tags: meaning, blackletter

A family member of mine has an old bier stein with a word written on the front. I studied German, but I have forgotten too much so I can't read it anymore. Can you tell me what is says, or if it's a proper noun? It looks like 'Profil' or something, but I can barely read the archaic calligraphy.

[image]

Comment: Some maybe interesting trivia: *Bierstein* is a nice English neologism apparently based on German. And it is not the least bit German - In German, *Bierstein* means an ugly residue left in the brewing equipment that needs to be removed (similar to *Weinstein*). So that word is the English counterpart of "Handy". Your item is a "Bierkrug" in German.

Comment: It's fun to see that a question with the term “Bier” in it is viewed almost 1000 times in just a few hours. :-)

Answer (score 37):

It says *Prosit*. That’s a toast like “Cheers!” or “Bottoms up!”, so it fits the Bierstein. *Prosit* has its origins in the Latin verb *prodesse*, which means *to serve (a purpose)* or *to be useful*. The literal meaning would be something like “it (the drink) shall be useful (or beneficial)”. Today, mostly the shorter form *Prost* is used.

The word is written in the old [Fraktur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur) script of the Latin alphabet. In today’s German writing, two forms of the letter *s* are used: The “normal” *s* and the *Eszett* or *sharp s,* *[ß](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F)*. Fraktur offered a third form, the *[long s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s), ſ*. The *Prosit* or *Proſit* on the Bierstein is written with that glyph.

Comment: Also, the word prosit is not entirely gone, see the drinking song ;)

Comment: In Fraktur, the modern 's' was used at the end of a word, and the 'f'-like glyph in the middle. Similar to Greek, where the letter sigma has two distinct forms depending on whether it is at the end of the word or not.

Comment: The long s was also used in English orthography until the 1800s.

Comment: "prosit" is a Latin word used in German, 3rd person singular present subjunctive, "may it be beneficial".

Answer (score 6):

### Proſit

The 4<sup>th</sup> letter is a »long s«. German used to have three different types of s:

- **s** = »rundes S« (round S)
- **ß** = »scharfes S« (sharp S), also called »Eszett« because it derives froma ligature of long S (»Es«) (ſ) and Z (»Zett«) (ʒ) (in fractur writing)
- **ſ** = »langes S« (long S)

German had special orthographic rules for the usage of those three letters. For more details see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s

Today German has only two kinds of s (»s« and »ß«). When ever the long s had to be used in fractur writing, you use the round s now.

But this is only true for German German and Austrian German. In Swiss German also the ß is obsolete, so in Swiss German you use only the letter s. The rules are:

- If it had to be **ſ** before, use **s** now. (In all tree German Langauges)
- If it is **ß** in German German or Austrian German, use **ss** instead. (Only in Swiss German).

This second rule (ß -> ss) can also be used if you write all UPPERCASE (becasue there is no uppercase »ß« in Standard German), or if you have tecnicalProblems with »ß« (i.e. when using a non-german Keyboard).